# Need some advice for duplicated queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a lot of duplicated queries (in django debug toolbar) when i load my menu tabs, im sure i can optimize this but don't find the good way.

Models :

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

    def getscateg(self):
         return self.souscategorie_set.all().filter(visible = True)


class SousCategorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def gettheme(self): 
        return self.theme_set.all().filter(visible = True)


class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    souscategorie = models.ForeignKey('SousCategorie')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views :

```
def page(request):
    categs = Categorie.objects.filter(visible = True)

    return render(request, 'page.html', locals())
```

Templates :

```
{% for categ in categs %}

    <li>
        {{categ.name}}
        <ul>
            {% for scateg in categ.getscateg %}

                <li>
                    {{scateg.name}}
                    <ul>

                         {% for theme in scateg.gettheme %}

                             <li>{{ theme.name }}</li>      

                         {% endfor %}                  

                    </ul>             
                </li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

I have look at prefetch_related but only work if i want load Categorie from SousCategorie and SousCategorie from Theme, so if i understand i need the contrary of this...

Answer (score 2):

Solved !

If it can help :

```
from .models import Categorie, SousCategorie, Theme, SousTheme
from django.db.models import Prefetch

pf_souscategorie = Prefetch('souscategorie_set', SousCategorie.objects.filter(visible=True)) 
pf_theme = Prefetch('souscategorie_set__theme_set', Theme.objects.filter(visible=True)) 
pf_soustheme = Prefetch('souscategorie_set__theme_set__soustheme_set', SousTheme.objects.filter(visible=True)) 

categs = Categorie.objects.filter(visible=True).prefetch_related(pf_souscategorie, pf_theme, pf_soustheme)
```

and call like this in the template :

```
{% with currscat=categ.souscategorie_set.all %}
{% with currth=souscateg.theme_set.all %}
{% with currsth=theme.soustheme_set.all %}
```

Bye

Answer (score 1):

In Django every time you evaluate a new queryset a query is executed, so you need to reduce the number of queryset being used. Here is what is happening:

- You create a queryset `Categorie.objects.filter(visible=True)` and it is passed into the view layer, there the first query is executed at the this tag `{% for categ in categs %}`
- Inside the loop, for every category you're calling a method `categ.getscateg` which returns a new queryset `return self.souscategorie_set.all().filter(visible = True)`, this queryset will be executed at the second loop in your template `{% for scateg in categ.getscateg %}`
- The same thing happens with `{% for theme in scateg.gettheme %}`

Using `prefetch_related` was the right move, try something like (didn't test it):

`Categorie.objects.filter(visible=True, souscategorie_set__visible=True, souscategorie_set__theme_set__visible=True).prefetch_related('souscategorie_set__theme_set')`

`prefetch_related` works by running a first query to load the categories that satisfy your current filter, then it executed a second query to load all subcategories and so on.

In other cases you can use `select_related`, but that only works when a single query can be used, as an example, it would work if you needed the category and subcategory of a theme, like:

`Theme.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related('souscategorie__categorie')`

The difference here is that Theme is the one that has the `ForeignKey`, so it has only one subcategory, and it can be loaded with a single join, that means you can use `select_related` only when your queryset is from the Model that points and I think that it also works with `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually your proposition don't work for me i got this error : Cannot resolve keyword 'souscategorie_set' into field. Ill try to find a way with this approach. Actually in django-debug-toolbar i got 97 duplicate for 105 queries but the majority of them take 0ms to execute, so no impact in the page loading, i think i should post my real template and the queries log for expose my problem.

Comment: I used the information that you gave in your question, if you're getting this error the name is wrong, have a look on the page about [acessing related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/). 105 queries is really bad, even if it runs with 0ms now, you should try to fix it. Also, I recommend reading the [docs about optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/)

Answer (score 0):

I have reduce my querysets by 2 by using "with"

It's a good point but i always got a lot of duplicate (like 44 duplicate for 51 queries), for example i hit my database when i do that :

```
 {% for categ in categs %}
    {% with currscat=categ.getscateg %} 

        <li class = "{% if currscat %} has_menu {% endif %}"> {{categ.name}}  # This line hit database

            {% if currscat %} # This line hit database 

                  <ul class = "menu-1"> ... </ul>

            {% endif %}

        </li> 

    {% endwith %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I try to use prefetch_related like this :

```
categs = Categorie.objects.filter(visible=True).prefetch_related('souscategorie_set')
```

but thats just add query to database, don't reduce...

Some advice?

Thanks